# Why does my LED blink when too much voltage is applied?

Tags: arduino, diodes

I bought a set of simple light-emmiting diodes. Connecting one to Arduino's full 5V output (without a resistor) causes the diode to blink. However changing the duty cycle to a value below 80% causes the diode to emit constant light.

What causes this behaviour? From my (limited) knowledge of physics I would assume that a diode should either emit constant light or no light at all, regardless of the voltage.

Comment: Duty cycle is a percentage between 0% and 100%. Its, the percent of time on over a period.

Comment: This isn't a standard behavior.  When you over-drive an LED long enough it simply fails.  Sometimes the color will change before failure.  You always want to have a resistor in series with an LED to keep the current within spec (usually 20mA for a "standard" LED).  Perhaps the Arduino has a protection circuit that is limiting the current to protect itself?

Comment: so you connect an LED to a PWM pin, and when you run it at 100%, your LED blinks ? When its less than 80%, your LED is constant. Is that correct ? Do you have a resistor for your LED ?

Comment: @efox29 I didn't have a resistor on hand, so I tested it without one.

Comment: It could be that you are attempting to draw to much current from the pin and the Arduino is resetting.

Comment: Setting the pin to 80% doesn't reduce the voltage, only the duty cycle. You still need the resistor!

Comment: Is there any chance that you are using a LED with a built-in blinker / flasher circuit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I definitely second Russell's answer.  You're just asking to break something by not limiting the current to be within both specs.

That said, you're probably getting saved by your power supply.  The LED has a particular forward voltage that is less than the supply voltage, and the remaining voltage basically sees a short circuit.  (that's what the resistor is for that you don't have)  So:

1. The supply collapses
2. The Arduino resets, which turns off the LED as a side-effect
3. The supply becomes unloaded and comes back
4. The Arduino comes out of reset and starts over running code, which turns the LED back on
5. The supply collapses
6. The Arduino resets
7. Etc.

Like the other comments, PWM does NOT reduce the voltage.  It only chops it up so that it's full-on for (x)% of the time and full-off for (100-x)% of the time.  Over many on/off periods, the *average* value is reduced, but not the instantaneous value.  Do this faster than your eye can keep track of it (>30Hz), and it appears to be constant and dimmed, but a high speed camera or other suitable instruments will show that it's still blinking at full brightness.

Answer (score 3):

Analogy

- I rev my car which has a 6000 RPM redline to 15000 RPM,

  It suddenly loses power for a few seconds then climbs back to 15000 RPM again and repeats the cycle.

  Why does it do this?

ie You are driving the LED and the Arduino outside their "envelopes".
Both are competing to be the first to die.
They are politely telling you this.
Hope that the LED wins (as they usually cost less than Arduinos).

The internal drive transistor for the pin may be overheating and going off for a quiet cuppa before trying again.

As efox29 suggests - the Arduino could be resetting.

Whatever is happening, as what you are doing is outside specification for both components there is no certainty that the action you see will be well described by a data sheet.

Don't do it.